# Flutter Get_Storage: GetStorage.init(), reads data from the local disk only once on startup?

Tags: flutter

I have the following code using Get_Storage package to store locally some values:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

void main() async {
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const App());
}

class Controller extends GetxController {
  final box = GetStorage();

  int value1 = 0;

  void changeValue(int value) {
    value1 = value;
    box.write('value', value);
    update();
  }

  void readValue1() {
    value1 = box.read('value') ?? 0; // Read the value from storage
    update();
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final getStorageFolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final fileWithExtension = '${getStorageFolder.path}/$GetStorage.gs'; // Add the get_storage file extension
    return File(fileWithExtension);
  }

  Future<int> readValue2() async {
    final file = await _localFile;

    final contents = await file.readAsString();
    final jsonData = json.decode(contents);

    final int isvalue = jsonData['value'] ?? 0;
    box.write('value', isvalue);

    value1 = isvalue;
    update();
    return isvalue;
  }
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<Controller>(
      init: Controller(),
      initState: (_) {},
      builder: (gtx) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text("${gtx.value1}"),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      gtx.changeValue(42);
                    }, // Pass a value here
                    child: const Text("Write"),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: gtx.readValue1,
                    child: const Text("Read1"),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: gtx.readValue2,
                    child: const Text("Read2"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

If i change some values inside the get_storage file manually and save it and than try to read it, it shows me always the value that was read at the start of the app.

It is because the key-value are in memory?

To make this work i uses traditional file I/O to read a JSON file, parse its contents, and retrieve the 'value' field.

Is there any way from the get_storage package to accomplish this?
Or is there any other package who can read and write key-value locally?

Thanks in advance for some help